# Getting apex_util.json_from_sql to return 0.5

Tags: jquery, json, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm working with Application Express and Jquery. If my field contains the value of 0.5 Oracle returns it as .5 without the zero. This causes jQuery JSON parser to choke.

```
declare v_sql varchar2(4000);

begin
    v_sql := 'select 0.5 xyz from dual';
    apex_util.json_from_sql (v_sql);
end;
```

Returns:

```
{"row":[{"XYZ":.5}]}
```

I want:

```
{"row":[{"XYZ":0.5}]}
```

Is there some way to direct json_from_sql to put in the leading zero if required for all decimal fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing a string replace on the client side

```
json = json.replace(/\:\./g, ":0.");
```

Before calling parseJSON

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there are no options to json_from_sql, which annoyingly enough is still not documented in the official documentation. It may be there is an implicit to_char happening on the field, removing the leading zero.
This is in the spec of htmldb_util, and there are no comments.

```
procedure json_from_sql (
    sqlq     in varchar2 default null,
    p_sub    in varchar2 default 'N',
    p_owner  in varchar2 default null);
```

When you execute the select from the SQL workshop > SQL commands the zero is also not displayed.
I know it's not thrilling, but you may consider putting a to_char around your numbers:

```
v_sql := 'select TO_CHAR(0.5,''FM9990D0'') xyz from dual';
```